# Java Messaging System

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Java file send program.  Right now I am attempting to implement a chat messaging system.

Here is the code for calling the Server/Client code:

```
if(host.isSelected()) {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerChat serverChat = new ServerChat();
        server.Thread();
        serverChat.Thread();
    }
else if(guest.isSelected()) {
        Client client = new Client();
        ClientChat clientChat = new ClientChat();
        client.Thread();
        clientChat.Thread();
}
```

This calls the code in the following classes: ServerChat

```
public class ServerChat extends Main implements Runnable {

public static ServerSocket ss;
public static Socket s;
public static DataInputStream dis;
public static DataOutputStream dos;

public void Thread() {
    (new Thread(new ServerChat())).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String variable = "";

    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        s = ss.accept();

        dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        while (!variable.equals("exit")) {
            variable = dis.readUTF();
            chatText.setText(chatText.getText().trim() + "\n Client:\t" + variable);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if (send.isSelected()) {
        try {
            String messageOut = "";
            messageOut = chatText.getText().trim();
            dos.writeUTF(messageOut);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

ClientChat code:

```
public class ClientChat extends Main implements Runnable {

    public void Thread() {
        (new Thread(new ClientChat())).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            String variable = "";

            while (!variable.equals("exit")) {
                variable = dis.readUTF();
                chatText.setText(chatText.getText().trim() + "\n Server:\t" + variable);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (send.isSelected()) {
            try {
                String messageOut = "";
                messageOut = chatText.getText().trim();
                dos.writeUTF(messageOut);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

They are able to connect to each other, but the data is not being posted into the text boxes which I have created in the main class. (All the elements needed from main are public).

When I connect (via locahost) I create the server through a new class and open up a new thread

```
public class Server extends Main implements Runnable {

public ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
public String file;
public DataOutputStream dos;
public DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##, #00");
public BufferedReader inFromClient;

public void Thread() {
    (new Thread(new Server())).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        chatText.append("Local IP Address : " + localaddr);
        chatText.append("Local hostname : " + localaddr.getHostName());
        String clientSentence = null;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        String file = "";
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##, #00");

        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            inFromClient
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        chatText.append("Unable to create server");
        chatText.append("Can't detect local host : " + e);
    }
}
```

The Same goes for the Client:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {

public DataOutputStream dos;
public DataInputStream dis;
public Socket skt;
public StringTokenizer st;

public void Thread() {
    try {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(skt.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    (new Thread(new Client())).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            String data = dis.readUTF();
            st = new StringTokenizer(data);
            String CMD = st.nextToken();
            JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
            open.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = open.getSelectedFile();
            String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            switch (CMD) {
                case "CMD_SENDFILE":
                    try {
                        fileName = st.nextToken();
                        System.out.println("Receiving file...");
                        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
                        File file = new File(path + "/Downloads" + fileName + ".txt");
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        InputStream input = skt.getInputStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int count, percent = 1;
                        while ((count = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            percent = percent + 1;
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }

                        fos.close();
                        System.out.println("File was saved: " + path);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        DataOutputStream eDos = new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        skt.close();
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        /*String string = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Incoming: " + string + "\n");
        System.out.println("Incoming: " + in.readLine() + "\n");
        //in.close();*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error could not connect\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Let me guess -- your GUI is a Swing GUI, and if you try to chat with it, it becomes completely frozen, is that close?

Comment: If so, your code completely ignores all threading concerns (not to mention ignoring all exceptions -- something you should **never** do).

Comment: Yes it is a swing but i have created a new thread so that it does not freeze

Comment: You'll want to improve this question then including posting more code, code that is as close to a [mcve] as you can. Please read the requirements to learn more about this tool. We need to see how your GUI and non-GUI code is interacting, something we can't see well. And yes, you are ignoring threading concerns as you're making Swing calls within background threads, something that can cause intermittent hard to debug exceptions. But first of all, please at least print your stacktraces from within your catch blocks. You may be throwing exceptions and not knowing about them.

Comment: Note that the [mcve] is not a complete code dump, and we don't accept code posted in links, just code posted here. I post this so that you'll have the best chances of getting a decent answer to your question.

Comment: The main class is a JForm that I constructed

Comment: Great, but I still can't see at all how your two codes are interacting. **Again** make sure that none of your catch blocks are empty. First things first -- within them print the stack trace to be sure that you're not missing exceptions. This is very important. Next, improve the code you're posting.

Comment: The only thing I can tell you based on the code you've posted is (again) 1) don't ignore the exceptions as you're doing, and 2) Make sure that you make all Swing calls on the Swing event thread. Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see how to do this, and why this is important.

Comment: I have added some more code.  i don't know if this is a problem but when I open up the server I am creating a new thread.  Moreover, I think I may be unintentionally trying to create a new server when create the chat feature as well.  I call both the Server and the ChatServer at one time.

Comment: Netbeans has exactly nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
public class ClientChat extends Main implements Runnable {
```

You're mis-using inheritance. Inheritance is not used so that one instance can share variables with another, which is what you're trying to use it for. Instead it's mainly used to share behaviors. I strongly urge that ClientChat not extend Main but rather has a Main field, one whose public methods it can call.

Your other two problems are lesser problems, but they still will cause you headaches:

- You generally want to avoid ignoring exceptions as you're doing. At least have the catch block print the stacktrace: `e.printStackTrace();`.
- You will want to be sure that Swing calls, including calls to `setText(...)` on text components, be made on the Swing event thread. If you're using a plain vanilla thread, then this can be done via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});`. Otherwise consider using a SwingWorker which will help automate this for you with its publish / process method pair.

---

You've asked:

> About inheritance, is there any post I can look at for calling main fields for the ClientChat?

Look up "inheritance vs composition"  -- you would be using the latter, composition here, not inheritance.

You would likely want to pass information back and forth between the GUI, or "view" portion of your code, with the chat engine or "model" portion of your code. There are several ways to do that, but usually they'd be connected by some type of "control" class or classes, something known as the "MVC" or "Model-View-Controller" architecture.

Comment: About inheritance, is there any post I can look at for calling main fields for the ClientChat?